# Intellij Idea 10.5 incredible slow on typing Groovy syntax

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

since i installed the patch today, groovy syntax is incredibly slow, it takes about 10 seconds to write my code changes, anyone konw what to do?

Comment: I have not found a proper fix for this, it appears to happen when intellij index's/validates SQL strings written in queries such as... sql.eachRow( 'select * from tableName' ), so, to overcome it, i had to store the SQl in a variable and pass it into the closure: sql.eachRow(theSqlVariable)... This way, intellij doesnt know that your string is sql at the time you declare it, and so it doesnt try to validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Please [file an issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA) with the [CPU snapshot](http://www.jetbrains.net/devnet/docs/DOC-192).